# Building an AST with code quotations vs Expression Trees

Tags: reflection, f#

I have some problems building a expression tree. I can do the same thing when using code quotations but I had no luck sofar doing it via expressions.

First have a look at my approach doing it via code quotations

```
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns

    type Container<'a> = Container of 'a
    type FromD<'a> = {a: Container<'a>; b: Container<'a>}
    type ToD<'a> = {a: Container<'a>; b: Container<'a>}

    let private eval e = QuotationEvaluator.Evaluate e

    let f1 f =
        let ex =
            <@
                fun (x:FromD<'a>) ->
                {
                    a = f x.a;
                    b = f x.b
                } 
                : ToD<'b>
            @>
        eval ex
```

The signature of the above is `(Container<'a> -> Container<'b>) -> (FromD<'a> -> ToD<'b>)`. Exactly what I wanted. The Expression tree generated by `f1` is

```
Lambda (x,
        NewRecord (ToD`1,
                Application (ValueWithName (<fun:r1@60>, f),
                                PropertyGet (Some (x), a, [])),
                Application (ValueWithName (<fun:r1@60>, f),
                                PropertyGet (Some (x), b, []))))
```

Now some test code that transforms `FromD` into a `ToD` and applies a transformation on the `Container` as well

```
    let transform (Container (v:'a)) : Container<'b> = Container (sprintf "%A" v)

    [<Test>]
    let ``test F1`` () =
        let r1 = f1 transform {a = Container true; b = Container true}
        let r2 = f1 transform {a = Container 1; b = Container 2}
        printfn "F1: %A, F1: %A" r1 r2
```

Everything is exactly like I wanted and `r1` and `r2` yield the expected results.

Now I want to recreate `f1` using expressions instead of code quotations.
This is my first try (with some helper functions)

```
//fields :: Type -> PropertyInfo []
let fields t = FSharpType.GetRecordFields t

//nameMap :: Type -> Map<string,PropertyInfo>
let nameMap t =
    t
    |> fields
    |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Name, x)
    |> Map.ofArray

let f2<'x, 't> f = 
    let xt = typeof<'x>
    let tt = typeof<'t>
    let ps = nameMap xt
    let x = Var("x", xt)
    let vx = Expr.Var(x)
    let fnv = Expr.ValueWithName(f, "f")
    let ex = 
        Expr.Lambda(x,
            Expr.NewRecord(tt,
                [
                    Expr.Application(fnv, Expr.PropertyGet(vx, ps.Item "a", []))
                    Expr.Application(fnv, Expr.PropertyGet(vx, ps.Item "b", []))
                ])) 

    let ex2 : Expr<'x -> 't> = ex |> Expr.Cast
    let ex3 = eval ex2
    ex3
```

and some test code

```
let ``test F2`` () =
    let r3 = (f2<FromD<bool>, ToD<string>> transform) {a = Container true; b = Container true}
    printfn "R3 %A" r3
```

Now the first thing is that in this case the signature of `f2` is
`(Container<obj> -> Container<string>) -> ('x -> 't)`
instead of
`(Container<'a> -> Container<'b>) -> (FromD<'a> -> ToD<'b>)`
So somehow the type infererrer is a bit to eager on this one.

This the leads then to the following error message

```
System.ArgumentException : Type mismatch when building 'f': function argument type doesn't match. Expected 'tst+Container`1[System.Boolean]', but received type 'tst+Container`1[System.Object]'.
Parameter name: receivedType
at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.checkTypesSR[a] (System.Type expectedType, System.Type receivedType, a name, System.String threeHoleSR) [0x00019] in <57acd2f6dff9fae1a7450383f6d2ac57>:0
at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.checkAppliedLambda (Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr f, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr v) [0x00084] in <57acd2f6dff9fae1a7450383f6d2ac57>:0
at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.mkApplication (Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr v_0, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr v_1) [0x00001] in <57acd2f6dff9fae1a7450383f6d2ac57>:0
at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr.Application (Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr functionExpr, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr argument) [0x00001] in <57acd2f6dff9fae1a7450383f6d2ac57>:0
at tst.f2[x,t] (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] f) [0x0005f] in <582303e818eafa12a7450383e8032358>:0
at tst.test F2 () [0x00005] in <582303e818eafa12a7450383e8032358>:0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in <8cd55ece525b4760b63de40980e005aa>:0
```

So it seems that there is some issue while constructing the expression tree as the type inferer says my function has a `bool` type param but the actual param is `object`.
Now I can overcome this by rewriting the function like this

```
let f2<'x, 't> f = 
    let xt = typeof<'x>
    let tt = typeof<'t>
    let ps = nameMap xt
    let x = Var("x", xt)
    let vx = Expr.Var(x)
    let fnv = Expr.ValueWithName(f, typeof<Container<bool> -> Container<string>>, "f")
    let ex = 
        Expr.Lambda(x,
            Expr.NewRecord(tt,
                [
                    Expr.Application(fnv, Expr.PropertyGet(vx, ps.Item "a", []))
                    Expr.Application(fnv, Expr.PropertyGet(vx, ps.Item "b", []))
                ])) 

    let ex2 : Expr<'x -> 't> = ex |> Expr.Cast
    let ex3 = eval ex2
    ex3
```

In this case I force the `ValueWithName` to be of a specific type instead of `f.GetType()`.
I have created for this example a very specific type (`typeof<Container<bool> -> Container<string>>`) also to make the example easier to understand.

This will help me to get past the construction phase and also is working with the cast.
Also the expression tree that got constructed is the same as before.

However now it crashes during evaluation with the following error message

```
System.ArgumentException : Argument types do not match
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant (System.Object value, System.Type type) [0x00049] in <4a648327db854c86ab0ece073e38f4b3>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.LetRecConvExpr (FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes+ConvEnv env, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] letrec, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr inp) [0x00185] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.ConvExpr (FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes+ConvEnv env, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr inp) [0x00001] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.LetRecConvExpr (FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes+ConvEnv env, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] letrec, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr inp) [0x02065] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.ConvExpr (FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes+ConvEnv env, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr inp) [0x00001] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes+ConvExprs@703.Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr inp) [0x00001] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult] (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] mapping, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T] x) [0x0003f] in <57acd2f6dff9fae1a7450383f6d2ac57>:0
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule.Map[T,TResult] (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] mapping, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T] list) [0x00001] in <57acd2f6dff9fae1a7450383f6d2ac57>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.ConvExprs (FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes+ConvEnv env, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T] es) [0x00007] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.LetRecConvExpr (FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes+ConvEnv env, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] letrec, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr inp) [0x020e6] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.ConvExpr (FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes+ConvEnv env, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr inp) [0x00001] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.LetRecConvExpr (FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes+ConvEnv env, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] letrec, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr inp) [0x027f0] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.ConvExpr (FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes+ConvEnv env, Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr inp) [0x00001] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.Conv[a] (a e, System.Boolean eraseEquality) [0x0001d] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.CompileImpl[a] (a e, System.Boolean eraseEquality) [0x00001] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluationTypes.Compile[a] (a e) [0x00001] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator.QuotationEvaluator.Evaluate[T] (Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr`1[T] e) [0x00001] in <56703c1ea378c767a74503831e3c7056>:0
at tst.f2[x,t] (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] f) [0x000f5] in <5823081418eafa12a745038314082358>:0
at tst.test F2 () [0x00005] in <5823081418eafa12a745038314082358>:0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in <8cd55ece525b4760b63de40980e005aa>:0
```

Does anybody have an idea whats going on?

Comment: It has the type `'x -> 't` because that's exactly how you cast it. The compiler did precisely what you asked of it. As for the type of `f` being fixed to `obj`, that's because there is nothing in the code that would point the compiler to what the type of `f` must be.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin yeah sure - but this is only bc otherwise I wouldnt even get it to compile. So I am not bound to this implementation as long as I can express a function with a actually working signature of  
`(Container<'a> -> Container<'b>) -> (FromD<'a> -> ToD<'b>)`  
So I am open to other suggestions. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `f2` ends with `'x -> 't`, because that's exactly how you specified it on this line:

```
let ex2 : Expr<'x -> 't> = ex |> Expr.Cast
```

`f2` doesn't even know about the existence of such things as `FromD` and `ToD`, so it can't possibly have them in its type.
If you look at the type of the first part of `r3` in your test, however, you will see that it is `FromD<_> -> ToD<_>`, because those are specified as type arguments to `f2` to stand in for `'x` and `'t` respectively.

As for `Container<obj>` - it's actually a bit worse than you think. If you look at `f2` in isolation, you'll see that its type is `obj -> 'x -> 't`. That is because there is nothing in the body of `f2` to suggest what the type of `f` should be. So it's coerced to just `obj` as the ultimate supertype of all.
When you actually *use* `f2` with argument `transform` for parameter `f` - that's when the compiler fixes the type of `f` to be `Container<_> -> Container<string>` (since that's the type of `transform`), which later becomes `Container<obj> -> Container<string>`, because there is nothing in the program to constrain the type further.

From the above, the fix is self-evident: just declare the type of `f` explicitly.

```
let f2<'x, 't, 'a, 'b> (f: Container<'a> -> Container<'b>) = 
    ...
```

This will give you the right types even before the first application.

**But beware!**
Since all your processing is happening at runtime, the compiler cannot guarantee you type safety in all places. Therefore, you must take care to guard against them yourself. Here are some (though possibly not all) of the things on which your code relies that are not compile-time enforceable:

1. Type `'x` must be a record with fields named `a` and `b` of type `'a`.
2. Type `'t` must be a record with exactly two fields, named `a` and `b`, declared in that specific order, and both having type `'b`.

Such design seems a bit wobbly to me. Perhaps if you described your original problem (preferably as a separate question), someone could suggest a more elegant solution.

If you just want to "map over record", I would perhaps look at a less ambitious solution, e.g.:

```
let fromDMap f (fromD: FromD<_>) : ToD<_> = { a = f fromD.a; b = f fromD.b }

// Usage:
let r3 = fromDMap transform {a = Container true; b = Container true}
```

Of course, this approach won't work if you want to make a "generic" function for mapping namesake fields of arbitrary types. But then, I would venture that such function would be a bit *too generic*.

---

**P.S.** Your function `transform` has a declared type that's more generic than the function actually is. The declared return type is `Container<'b>`, but what it actually returns is `Container<string>`. Thus `'b` gets constrained to be `string`.

Comment: Nope, that wont work for me. I cant define it that way as `f2` is in reality much much more flexible than what you see in the example (therefore also the need to construct it via expressions instead of quotations). What I want is a function `f2 :: g[j[a]] -> (j[a] -> j[b]) -> h[j[b]]` (Haskell syntax) but this I cant express in the signature of F#. So putting `(Container<'a> -> Container<'b>)` is not an option

Comment: OK - taking a hint from you I got the thing solved.

The function signature must look that way `let f2<'x, 't, 'f> (f:'f)` and on the call site `f2<FromD<bool>, ToD<string>, Container<bool> -> Container<string>> transform`

Comment: You can't require a type parameter to itself be a type constructor with its own type parameters. This is called "higher-kinded types" (compare to "higher-order functions"), and F# doesn't have them.